# How do zebra finches mate?

Tags: breeding, birds, zebra-finch

I got a pair of zebra finches who are not successful in breeding, Every turn the female lays 1-3 eggs but none is fertilized.

I'm wondering if they do ever mate? I've seen mating in other birds but I see no similar action done by my birds. They often spend the night in the nest together and they take turns sitting on the eggs so they seem like being paired and ok with each other but then why are they not mating?

Comment: Do you have two nests now? As I stated in you last question? This site is not a one way road, we need answers of you too...

Comment: @Allerleirauh Thanks for looking in to this,  I tried to make my question general and not specific to my problem, I would like to know how zebra-finches mate?

Comment: considering your other comment about two nests I wasn't able to find any source supporting that and didn't go with it. They have only one nest

Comment: *"Finches will also use nesting boxes you place in the cage.Try small wicker or even plastic baskets or bowls. Place **a couple** throughout the cage."* Source: [wikihow to breed zebra finch](https://www.wikihow.pet/Breed-Zebra-Finches) Costed me 5 sec of googling...

Comment: @Allerleirauh yes I read that but got the impression that the instruction is to let the birds decide which nest they like the best since it later says "You can also remove the other nesting boxes if you don't have other breeding pairs in the same cage."